# Save list of images from models django

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 3 and I want to create a Model where I upload a tensor file (called ct), then I elaborate it, extract the slices of this tensor and save the single slices as different images.

here is my model:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    slug = ShortUUIDField(max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #...
    ct = models.FileField()
    # here I want to save a series of images that I extracted from the tensor 'ct'
```

- 'ct' is a 3D scan that I have to upload as a file
- The number of images extracted is not constant.
- I have a function called 'get_slices' that receives a ct and returns the images to be saved

Can you please help me step by step?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another model and connect it to the original model (with ForeignKey).
Use ImageField if you just want to save the image

```
class Case(models.Model):
    slug = ShortUUIDField(max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Use ct = models.ImageField(title) if you want to save at least one photo'ct'

class Case_images(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=case.title)
```

Use these codes when you want to upload a ct:

```py
def upload_a_ct(title, slug, ct):
    c = Case(slug=slug, title=title)
    c.save()
    for image in get_slices(ct):
        Case_images.objects.create(image=image, case=c)
```

Comment: My problem is how to tell Django to save those images.
In practice, I have a function called 'get_slices' that takes the ct and outputs a list of images. How can i save them in the imagefield? (this has to be fully automated, whenever I upload a ct)

CT is not an image but another type of file. It's a 3D scan

Comment: @Pezz create a Case without the image `c = Case(slug=slug, title=title)`, and save it `c.save()`. Then make an Case_images for the each image `Case_images.objects.create(image=image, case=c) for image in ct`

Comment: @Haken : I do not want to upload the images. I want to save them after elaborating another uploaded file and this has to be automatic. In the way you proposed it, I have just other fields where to upload.

Comment: @parhammed Where should I put this object.create?

Comment: @Pezz It's usually in "models.Model" and is automatically present on all Django models unless you change it manually

Comment: Where should i put this ---> Case_images.objects.create(image=image, case=c) for image in ct  ?

Comment: @Pezz that only an in-line code (`for image in ct: `(next line) `Case_images.objects.create(image=image, case=c)`)

Comment: @Pezz To better understand what I mean read my answer again i edit it

Comment: your answer does not answer my question. This has to be fully automatic, even if I upload a ct file from admin web page or from an API

Comment: @Pezz You better go and see a tutorial because you can't answer with a question and answer

Comment: I repeat. This is not an answer to my question. I still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is here:

> > > [Automatically save list of images in ImageField after upload - django 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455889/automatically-save-list-of-images-in-imagefield-after-upload-django-3) <<<