# Automatically save list of images in ImageField after upload - django 3

Tags: django, image

Working with Django 3, I have the following **model**:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    slug = ShortUUIDField(max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #....
    ct = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

class ModelImages(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="slices_images")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', editable=False)
    #....
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(editable=False)
```

Once 'ct' (a 3D image) is uploaded (and this works perfectly), I want to extract the slices of the 'ct' and save them as images in 'ModelImages' class.

I extract the images with a function called 'get_slices(ct)'

The images are hundreds for each 'ct'

This should be fully automatic.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you. Use a post save signal that will 'automatically' process the 3D image of a Case object after it is saved.

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Case(models.Model):
    slug = ShortUUIDField(max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #....
    ct = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

class ModelImages(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="slices_images")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', editable=False)
    #....
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(editable=False)

# This will be run anytime AFTER a Case object is saved.
def process_3d_image(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # this is run only on first save (creation)
    if created:
        # if get_slices is creating and saving ModelImages objects you can pass
        # the instance (which is the Case object) for the foreign key as well.
        get_slices(instance.ct)

post_save.connect(process_3d_image, sender=Case)
```

Beware! This will be a synchronous task meaning django will wait for this processing to be done before returning a response. Seeing as there are hundreds of images this could take a while..

### P.S..

My second suggestion would be to avoid this by using an asynchronous task manager such as [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps).

If you manage to setup Celery you could create an asynchronous task for saving the images from `ct` that would be done in the background without blocking your django app.

`tasks.py`

```py
from <module> import get_slices

@app.task()
def process_3d_image_async(case_ct):
    get_slices(case_ct)
```

modified `post_save` function if using Celery

```py
from .tasks import process_3d_image_async

# This will be run whenever a Case object is saved.
def process_3d_image(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # this is run only on first save (creation)
    if created:
        process_3d_image_async.delay(case_ct=instance.ct)
```

And last thing to note is if you do it asynchronously you'll want to know whether a `Case` object's file has finished being processed so my last suggestion would be to add a BooleanField column to your Case model with default value False that you then set to true in your async task after slicing.

However using Celery is only a suggestion!

Comment: I owe you many beers for your help! At the moment I'm using synchr. method but I'm gonna try Celery.

Comment: Just for info, I had to use `with transaction.atomic():` in order to save the **ModelImages**